# Multiple split between two chars to string array

Tags: c#

I need to split a string that consists of html elements.

I want to split between two chars "<" and ">".

```
var htmlElements = "<p>lorem ipsum</p><span>nisi sapien</span><ul><li>list items</li></ul>";
string[] arrayOfElements = htmlElements.Split('<', '>')[1];
```

Using this code only pulls out the first "p". I need to pull out every element to a string array. The closing tag `</p>` doesn't matter, i need only the starting tag for every element.

Desired output is a string array containing `p span ul li`

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: use HTMLAgilityPack.

Comment: See updated main post for desired output. I would like to solve it by NOT using a third party library

Comment: jquery can easily do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using *regular expressions* in order to *extract* (match) the required values:

```
string htmlElements = "<p>lorem ipsum</p><span>nisi sapien</span><ul><li>list items</li></ul>";

string[] arrayOfElements = Regex
  .Matches(htmlElements, @"<(\w+)>")
  .OfType<Match>()
  .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
  .ToArray();
```

Test

```
// p span ul li
Console.Write(string.Join(" ", arrayOfElements));
```

In *general case*, *parsing* html by means of regular expressions is a *bad idea*, but if you want just to obtain items' values it can be good enough.

Comment: It worked just as expected. I don't know why someone downvoted it?